# Android event that fires when telephony network coverage is available again

Tags: android, telephony

I'd like to know if there's some way to detect it, so when it happens, for example when you have gone through a very long underground tunnel or you have returned from being in a mountain where there's no telephony network coverage, I can fire a service to perform some opperations.

I thought that [android.telephony package](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary.html) could help with this, but unless I'm missing something the most near thing I get is being able to check the signal strength, which if it's done by long periods contiuosly is going to waste battery a lot (so I'm not much into this solution), but I see no event that fires when that happens.

Comment: you can try to subscribe to the broadcast event for
android.net.conn.BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED or
android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE android.net.nsd.STATE_CHANGED

Comment: @AngelKoh I'm going to check, thanks.